# Review Audits with dangerous links should be completely removed

Tags: discussion, review-audits, spam

Review audits with dangerous links such as this one should be completely removed.

Links like this are dangerous and shouldn't be used for audits.
Or the links should be `[redacted]` or they shouldn't lead to anything.

> [image: review]

Comment: How can we know they are dangerous?

Comment: *Or the links should be [redacted] or they shouldnt lead to anything* ... maybe not because then you might review as **Looks OK**

Comment: Then how do we audit that people are catching answers with dangerous links?

Comment: Completely remove it then?

Comment: @HereticMonkey It would be very easy to change just the `href`-value of all links in review audits to, say, `https://example.org`.They would look just like before but clicking on them is safe.

Comment: How should the automated process that creates audits determine which links are "unsafe"?

Comment: If you *think* it's dangerous, assume it is and don't click it.   For a question on Stack Overflow, that's not just a red flag - that's you witnessing an atrocity firsthand.

Comment: @leonheess Wouldn't that lead to a lot of failed audits though? This audit is obvious because the text states that it's spam. But not too long ago I saw someone editing links in legitimate answers so that instead of pointing to official documentation they went to some weird 3rd party site. There was also a user who would create posts with a link that said it was pointing to another SO post but actually linked to a pornographic image. Sometimes the URL is only sign that something is wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Detecting dangerous links is part of reviewing

Recognizing dangerous/spam links is a substantial part of the job of someone that's reviewing. Part of the goal of reviewing is to find such links and remove the content from the site, so those posts harm fewer people. I don't really see how removing/masking the links in audits helps determine that people are doing that job. Obviously, there's no way for such links to be removed/masked from non-audits, so why should they be removed from audits?

#### "Skip" if you don't feel comfortable making a correct review decision

If you feel it would be necessary to go to a link in order to determine the appropriate review action, but you are uncomfortable going to a potentially dangerous link, then your best course of action is to "skip" any reviews where you feel you'd need to visit the link in order to make a determination of which action to take. Even if that means you skip every single review which isn't obviously OK, your reviews are still beneficial to the site.

#### Perhaps set up an isolated environment for testing potentially harmful links (or just "skip")

Personally, I have an isolated environment set up specifically so I can investigate such potentially dangerous links. Setting that up was a choice I made in order to be able to more accurately review posts. However, I'm heavily involved with [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) and [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/), which are specifically looking for spam. I understand that not everyone will make the choice to set up such an environment, but that just means they should "skip" reviews where they feel they would need such an environment to be comfortable reviewing the current post.

Note that even if I wasn't involved with Charcoal/SmokeDetector, I'd still want to have such an environment, as there are a lot of links we encounter in the regular use of the internet which are potentially dangerous. It's nice to have available a way to test such links.

#### Not all links need to be tested beyond verifying the link's real URL is what's displayed.

For the specific example you provided, the reviewer should be able to tell that this example post is spam without needing to investigate the links further. In other words, in this case, and many cases, you should be able to accurately determine the correct review action without needing to actually go to the link in the post. Needing to go to the link is usually only necessary in cases where it's not obvious one way or the other what the link is pointing to.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense

Comment: I use sites like https://www.url2png.com/ to screen the dodgiest-looking links if I suspect spam - it typically loads pages well enough to allow determining if the link is legit or not.

Comment: Do note that there is a middle ground between spam and “Looks OK”: it’s called “delete”. I don’t need a sandbox to delete things that look fishy.

Comment: "*Skip if you don't feel comfortable*."  (+1)  Skipping reviews is seriously underrated (and a personal hobby of mine).